# Nginx proxy configuration to hit the backend api via http proxy

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, reverse-proxy

I need the Nginx web server to connect to a https server listening on port 443. The `https` server cannot be reached by `Nginx` server machine directly and to reach the `https` server the `nginx` server needs to set the `http_proxy` and `https:proxy` parameters.

We are earlier using Apache and have achieved the same using `ProxyRemote * http://10.23.45.32:3128` parameter which allows the apache server to connect to the remote `https` server through the proxy server.

We are in the process of moving from apache to Nginx and need to know how to add the proxy rules so that `Nginx` server can pass the request to `https` server.

I have the below configuration set up for Nginx.

```
server {
  listen       80;
  server_name  localhost;
  access_log  /var/log/nginx/localhost.access.log;
  location / {
         proxy_pass http://localhost:9000;
         proxy_http_version 1.1;
         proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
         proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
         proxy_set_header Host $host;
         proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
  }

  #below path is working fine
  location /cities.json {
    proxy_pass      http://hostname.net:8080/cities.json;
  }
  #below rule is working fine
  location /states/ {
    proxy_pass     http://hostname.net:8080;
  }
  #below rule is giving 504 gateway timeout error.
  location /auth {
    #cannot call https://authenticationserver.net directly and need to go through proxy by setting http_proxy to http://proxy.host.net:3128
    proxy_pass    https://authenticationserver.net:443;
  }
}
```

In Apache, I used to do the below configuration to set the proxy:

```
<VirtualHost *:8000>
  ServerName hostname.net
  <Location /balancer-manager>
    SetHandler balancer-manager
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from all
  </Location>
  <Proxy balancer://authncluster>
    BalancerMember https://target.host.net
  </Proxy>
  <Proxy *>
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow From All
  </Proxy>
  ProxyRemote * http://proxy.host.net:3128
  SSLProxyEngine On
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyPass /balancer-manager !
  ProxyPass /authn/ balancer://authncluster/authn/
  ProxyTimeout 300
</VirtualHost>
```

Hope this helps. Please let me know how to do the configuration in Nginx.

Comment: You appear to have a typo in your nginx config. `proxy_pass    https://authenticationserver.net: 443` wouldn't be valid.  You need to add a semicolon and I believe remove the space between the colon and 443.

Comment: I did the correction but still I am not able to connect to the server. Basically, to connect to the `authenticationserver.net` we need to go via proxy which needs to be set to `http://10.122.522.87:3128`. How to set the `http_proxy` in Nginx?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Post more background, what you're trying to achieve (big picture) and fine details - exactly what needs to map to what.

Comment: Hi @Tim. I have updated the question. Please let me know if you need any more clarifications.

Comment: I think you need Nginx as a front end web server, you want it to pass all the requests to a proxy server, which will in turn pass the request to another server, is that right? Do you need to proxy the whole domain, or just one directory? I think you need to explain things more clearly and simply. You've done what most people do, which is explain things in a way that makes sense to someone who already completely understands your systems and aims. Explain it like you would to an intelligent child.

Comment: Thanks @Tim. You have understood correctly. I need Nginx as a front end web server, which will pass specific requests matching `/authn` pattern to a proxy server, which will in turn pass the request to my targer server. Except that not all request should be hitting the proxy but only requests which match a `/authn` pattern should hit the target server through a proxy. Its similar to the way we `export http_proxy` and `export https_proxy` to access a target server through proxy in a linux shell. Just that we need to do the same in the `Nginx` server. Hope this is clear now.

Comment: I believe the answer I gave yesterday answers your question. It doesn't spoon feed it to you, you can't just copy and paste it in, but it gives you a pattern that should work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35625/discussion-between-pradeep-and-tim).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will do it (the paths will be wrong because your question doesn't appear to specify sufficient details. The key is that nginx chooses the most specific match possible - you can ready about that [here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html).

```
location / {
   proxy_pass http://localhost:9000;
   proxy_http_version 1.1;
   proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
   proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
   proxy_set_header Host $host;
   proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}

location /otherurl {
  proxy_pass http://localhost:9001;
  # etc
}

location /thirdurl {
  proxy_pass http://localhost:9002;
  # etc
}
```

Comment: Updated the question. Basically, I cannot access the `authenticationserver.net` directly and can access the same via setting the http_proxy which is 'http://ipaddress:3128'.How to do this configuration in Nginx? Please let me know.